# Facebook like button showing error when clicked

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to show facebook like button. When a user clicks on the button it should make a callback after a user successfully likes that page.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-width="200" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '510679165797120',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.6'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        console.log('hello'); 
    });
};      
</script>
```

But it is not working. When you click on the like button it shows an error.
Can someone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you need the callback for?

Comment: I want to make some custom event in a callback.

Comment: The reason I ask is that Facebook platform policy is very strict in what you can do. So what custom event?

Comment: I want to insert some data into database with the help of ajax.

Comment: what data exactly? what for? you need to be more specific. also, FQL is deprecated, so i removed that tag. it will stop working very soon even for older apps.

Comment: btw, what´s the error message exactly?

Comment: Its simply showing "Error" in red color when I am doing click on the like button

Comment: after doing click on facebook like button the button is hiding and in that place only "Error" is showing

Comment: @NewUser: check the demo, i have fixed the code... let me know...

Answer (score 1):

It could be worth changing the  `js.src` line. To me I see it as though this line is looking for a local file.

```
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

I previously used the following line, but I'm not sure of the difference to be truthful:

```
 js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1"
```

Comment: I am certainly no expert in this area; so if I'm completely wrong just comment and I will delete my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the code to like a Facebook page built for you directly by Facebook at this site --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

That way you avoid deprecation issues, etc.

Just go there, enter the pertinent info, grab the code they spit out and place it on your site.

*good luck!*

Answer (score 1):

> - **demo** : http://so.devilmaycode.it/facebook-like-button-showing-error-when-clicked/
> - The error happen because you are on localhost or not in the same domain you specidied in the app settings

### [image]

also in order to work, your callback function should be at the top like below

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '#############',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });

  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        console.log('hello'); 
  });

  };



  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```